# fetch the api data and put it inside the tables

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

- I am trying to fetch the api data and put it inside the tables, now i am using mock data
- so I was able to write successfully actions and reducers.
- now I am able to call the api.
- but in the network call I am not see response in the api and seeing blocked response content status.
- I am using react hooks for react and redux.
- this is where I am making the api call
  `useEffect(() => {
  getPosts(channel);
  }, []);`
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code snippet  and sandbox below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-kpt5i

```or-tag-here
demo.js

 const channel = useSelector(state => state.channel);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const getPosts = channel => dispatch(fetchPosts(channel));

  useEffect(() => {
    getPosts(channel);
  }, []);

actions.js

  export function fetchPosts(channel) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch(requestPosts());
    return fetch(`http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .then(
        response => response.json(),
        error => console.log("An error occurred.", error)
      )
      .then(json => {
        dispatch(receivedPosts(json));
      });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to your sample on codesandbox, it is due to you are loading from https site but your source is from http. change http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users to https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users will solve your issue.

Comment: can you tell me how to load the data inside the api

Comment: I see you dispatch  dispatch(receivedPosts(json)); but the receivedPosts expect json data contains articles whereas you endpoint return users. what do you expect to work here?

Comment: can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58355185/columns-should-be-added-only-after-i-slect-the-checkboxes